# Detemine which DLL allocated IntPtr

Tags: c#, memory-management, interop, intptr

I am working on a system that uses IntPtr's returned from two separate C++ DLLs.  The unmanaged memory is freed by calling the OBJECT_FREE method presented in each DLL.

Unfortunately, some of the code loses track of which DLL originally allocated the memory.  This results in an access violation since we have moved to Win7 (for some reason we were getting away with it on WinXP).

In the medium term, I will have to wrap up every IntPtr to deal with this properly, but in the short term, is there any way to determine which DLL allocated the memory originally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - an `IntPtr` is just a simple wrapper around an integer (actually a pointer) - there is no additional metadata and its obviously impossible to tell just from a number where it came from.

If you need to free memory associated with the `IntPtr` then I recommend that you [implement a safe handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182294.aspx) for each of your two separate C++ DLLs and modify your PInvoke calls to use safe handles instead, for example:

```
internal class FirstDllSafeHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private MySafeFileHandle()
        : base(true)
    {
    }

    override protected bool ReleaseHandle()
    {        
        return NativeMethods.FirstDll_OBJECT_FREE(handle);
    }
}

internal class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("whatever.dll")]
    public static extern void FirstDll_OBJECT_FREE(FirstDllSafeHandle handle);
    [DllImport("whatever.dll")]
    public static extern void FirstDll_GetObject(out FirstDllSafeHandle handle);

    [DllImport("whatever.dll")]
    public static extern void SecondDll_OBJECT_FREE(SecondDllSafeHandle handle);
    [DllImport("whatever.dll")]
    public static extern void SecondDll_GetObject(out SecondDllSafeHandle handle);
}
```

Using safe handles instead of `IntPtr` offers a number of other advantages as well seamlessly keeping track of the proper way of freeing resources associated with the `IntPtr`.

See [this MSDN blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/08/12/213808.aspx) on safe handles to learn more.

Comment: The problem is that he has two `OBJECT_FREE` methods in the 2 unmanaged libraries. So he will need also 2 `MySafeHandle` implementations each calling the correct free method.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Yes, this is the idea - I've reworded my answer a little to try and make this clearer.

Comment: The SafeHandle approach is definitely my medium term solution.  However due to the fact that this affects hundreds of calls, I was hoping for a quick win.  Obviously the IntPtr itself has no knowledge of where it comes from, I was hoping ther might be a Windows API call I might be able to use or some other mechanism as a short term hack.

Answer (score 1):

Given only an `IntPtr` there is no way to determine which unmanaged library allocated this chunk of memory.